# No roll argument in matplotlib axes3d view_init method

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I grab this image from the matplotlib documentation page on ["mplot3d View Angles"](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/toolkits/mplot3d/view_angles.html):

[image]

Based on the documentation, it seems that the method [`view_init()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.view_init.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.view_init) should have three arguments: `elev` (short for elevation), `azim` (short for azimuth), and `roll`. When I try passing the roll argument I get an error. So how can I adjust the roll angle of the camera position?

I tried to run [this program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bhhV.png), but there's an error.

Comment: [Please share all code as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: What version matplotlib are you using? It looks like the `roll` argument was added in version 3.6.